# Unable to explicitly cast a child class to another child class inside explicit implementation of interface in generic parent base class

Tags: c#, .net-4.7

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var first = new A();
        OtherClass.EnjoyLife(new OtherClass(first), OtherClass.Default);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public interface IInterface
    {
        void DoStuff(IInterface obj);
    }


    public abstract class AbstractBaseClass<T> : IInterface where T : AbstractBaseClass<T>
    {
        internal abstract void DoStuff(T obj);

        void IInterface.DoStuff(IInterface obj) => DoStuff((T)obj);
    }

    public class A : AbstractBaseClass<A>
    {
        internal override void DoStuff(A obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Do {obj}");
        }
    }

    public class B : AbstractBaseClass<B>
    {
        internal override void DoStuff(B obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Do {obj}");
        }

        public static explicit operator A(B obj) => new A();
    }

    public class OtherClass
    {
        public static readonly OtherClass Default = new OtherClass();
        private IInterface foo;

        private OtherClass()
        {
            this.foo = new B();
        }

        public OtherClass(IInterface bar)
        {
            this.foo = bar;
        }

        public static void EnjoyLife(OtherClass left, OtherClass right)
        {
            left.foo.DoStuff(right.foo);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I have an `InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'B' to type 'A'.'`
 being thrown when the explicit implementation of `DoStuff` is executed on `AbstractBaseClass<T>`. Why is it so even if an explicit cast from `B` to `A` is implemented on `B`?

Quite interestingly, if I replace

```
void IInterface.DoStuff(IInterface obj) => DoStuff((T)obj);
```

by

```
void IInterface.DoStuff(IInterface obj) => DoStuff((T)obj.GetType().GetMethod("op_Explicit").Invoke(null, new[] { obj }));
```

then it works perfectly fine. But I cannot this solution for other reasons.
I know the code is a bit circumvented but I don't see any reason why this should not work.

Comment: Can you show us the stack at the point of the exception? This is a bit hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

Based on what in the Main method and OtherClass, you should depend on abstraction, not on concrete classes while you override the DoStuff method
For example

```
internal override void DoStuff(IInterface obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Do {obj}");
}
```

but to do somthing like that you should remove the constraint on the abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass<T> : IInterface// where T : AbstractBaseClass<T>
```

and assign T to IInterface on concrete classes

```
public class A : AbstractBaseClass<IInterface>
```

I think if that will help you the abstract class here is useless you should implement the interface directly.

I need to know more and what the purpose of that design? because there are a lot of solutions if we know what you are trying to achieve.